# Any WYSIWYG editor based on XULRunner and SWT.Mozilla concept, JavaXPCOM

Tags: eclipse, firefox, eclipse-plugin, xul, xulrunner

Is there any open source WYSIWYG editor based on XULRunner, JavaXPCOM, and Mozilla browser which run on top of Eclipse as Eclipse plug-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See here http://sourceforge.net/projects/swt-composer/

If you're interested in a wysywyg-html editor based on the SWT browser and Java Script, checkout the HtmlComposer component from Mylyn Docs.

Comment: How to work on the above tool. I installed the tool but not getting the idea of using it. Any tutorial provided for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Bravo JSP Editor. It's not open source, but it has a free edition. http://bravo.comxa.com/

Hope it helps.